# Does Instagram API allow your app to take IG photos?

Tags: ios, api, instagram, photo

We're developing an iOS app that would require you to take a photo with Instagram, apply a filter, grab the new photo, and post it to our app. Does the Instagram API allow this?

I didn't find anything about that here: http://instagram.com/developer/

If not, what photo filter libraries could we use to mimic Instagram filters?

Comment: Just discovered this I think it should do the trick http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/#

Answer (score 1):

that will require you to upload the image to instagram and that is not allowed except for a few selected apps (Instamatic et al)

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
> 2. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

That said, You can still do the same on your own app:

http://getfilterkit.com/

or server:

http://zaachi.com/2013/08/19/php-photo-instagram-filters.html